# NullPointerException at Writer at at org.apache.log4j.helpers.CountingQuietWriter.write

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, log4j

I am getting the below error from a simple line of code having log.info statement

```
java.lang.NullPonterException
    at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.CountingQuietWriter.write(CountingQuietWriter.java:45)
    at org.apache.log4j.WritingAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:310)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingAppender.subAppend(RollingAppender.java:276)
    at org.apache.log4j.WritingAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachbleImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachbleImpl.java:66)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.info(Category.java:666)
    at com.bizcase.Helper.showTip(Helper.java:32)
```

Can anyone advice if this issue is encountered?

I am using log4j version 1.2.17 and normal rolling appender .

Its not a NullPonterException for null object.Its coming from log4j library and beyond my control to figure out which log4j property or code is causing this issue.

Comment: Install sources of log4j in your IDE and debug it. In exception row you will see reason of exception.

Comment: *"... beyond my control to figure out which log4j property or code is causing this issue."* - Advice: adjust that attitude.  It is not beyond the control of someone who 1) has access to the source code, and 2) has access to a debugger.

Comment: Note - see my answer, which proves that it not "beyond your control" to solve this.  (If I can get that far from just the stacktrace, *some* of the source code, and some simple logical deductions, then so could any programmer.)  It might be beyond your (current) skill level, but improving your skills >>is<< within your control.

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe, as it's a specific NPE, as your answer shows.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code<sup>1</sup>:

- "org.apache.log4j.helpers.CountingQuietWriter.write(CountingQuietWriter.java:45)" is a call to Writer.write(String).
- Writer.write(String) can only throw an NPE if the string is null.
- That means CountingQuietWriter.write was called with a `null` argument.

And so on.  (You can do the rest!)

I think you will find that the root cause is that `org.apache.log4j.Category.info(...)` is being called with a `null` message.

Also, note that the javadoc for `Category` states:

> There is absolutely no need for new client code to use or refer to the Category class. Whenever possible, please avoid referring to it or using it.

---

So, if `com.bizcase.Helper` is *your* code, then it needs to be revised, *both* to fix the NPE bug *and* to avoid direct usage of `Category`.

If it is not your code, you need to figure out where the null string comes from in the `info` call.  My guess would be is that it is a missing tool tip ... or something like that.

---

<sup>1 - I am hampered in this because I don't know the precise versions of Java and log4j that you are using, and therefore can't be sure I have the right source code.  And I don't know what the source of `com.bizcase.Helper` looks like.  On the other hand, you ... as the developer ... can find these things out.  Which makes it a whole lot easier *for you*.</sup>